# Tapestry 5: contributeRequestHandler in unit tests only

Tags: java, spring, tapestry

I'm trying to use `PageTester` in conjunction with spring security but am running into this exception:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can only process HttpServletRequest`

I think there is a solution (as below) but does anyone know how I can use the following contribution so that it gets called only during tests?

```
public static void contributeRequestHandler(OrderedConfiguration<RequestFilter> config, final RequestGlobals requestGlobals) {
  RequestFilter filter = new RequestFilter() {
   public boolean service(Request request, Response response,
     RequestHandler handler) throws IOException {
    requestGlobals.storeServletRequestResponse(mock(HttpServletRequest.class), mock(HttpServletResponse.class));
    return handler.service(request, response);
   }
  };
  config.add("EnsureNonNullHttpRequestAndResponse", filter, "before:*");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can provide extra modules in the [PageTester constructor](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/test/PageTester.html). which version are you using ?

Comment: Ah yes, of course - I should have looked at the documentation more closely :)

Comment: no prob, did your solution to mock http request for spring security work as you desribed? (just in case i ever need to integrate spring-security)